# "Bidirectional" type projection / variance in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, variance

Let's say we have a class hierarchy like `Pug : Dog : Mammal : Animal`.

I want a function that accepts a `Bag<T>` (where `Bag` is invariant in `T`) argument of things that are sub OR superclasses of Dog: `fun work(things: Bag<in/out Dog)` Such that `Bag<Animal>`, `Bag<Dog>`, `Bag<Pug>` is OK, but `Bag<Cat>` is NOT accepted.

Honestly, I'm not even sure what that type of projection is called. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

If you think about what `in` and `out` modifiers truly mean, you will soon realize having `in OR out` does not really make sense.

Let's take a look at `out` first. Having `<out T>` does not mean that "This function accepts `T` and its subclass as a parameter". It actually means "This function will not do anything a parameter of class  `T` or any of its subclasses cannot do". **This modifier imposes limitations on what you can do to that parameter.**

Check this code:

```
fun doThingsWithBag(bag: Bag<out Dog>) {
    bag.getAny().walk() // allowed

    bag.put(Dog()) // not allowed
}
```

You are not allowed to put any dog into this bag, because this bag could actually be a type `Bag<Pug>`, and `Bag<Pug>` won't accept a random `Dog`.

The same goes for `in`. `<in T>` does not mean that "This function accepts `T` and its super". It is more like "This function will not do anything `T` or any of its super classes cannot do".

```
fun doThingsWithBag(bag: Bag<in Dog>) {
    bag.put(Dog()) // allowed

    bag.getAny().walk() // not allowed
}
```

Now you can put a dog inside the bag, but you can't really do anything with the dogs inside the bag because the bag could actually be a `Bag<Animal>` and there is no guarantee that the "thing" you take out from the bag is a `Dog`.

So as you can see, there is a clear distinction between what `in` and `out` can do, and therefore they cannot coexist.

Even the interface suggested in the other answer won't help you much because your `Animal` class would also need to implement that same interface which means `Cat` will also have access to that interface. The only way to work around is to have your `work` method to accept `Bag<Any>` and manually check its generic class.

**Update:**

What you are trying to do is not possible in OOP. What you are looking for is basically something like this:

```
update(Animal()) // allowed
update(Dog())    // allowed
update(Pug())    // allowed
update(Cat())    // not allowed (compile time error)
```

However there is no way a compiler can stop you from doing this:

```
val animal: Animal = Cat()
update(animal)  // ???
```

You can do something similar to this only in runtime, by manually checking the input type.

Comment: That is all true, but there are use cases where this makes sense. In my case, I have a database operation that works on polymorphic types. Lets set I have `Repository<out T : DbModel>`, which contain `T` or some subclass of `T`. Now, I have a method, `updateFields(model: T, fields: Set<...>)`. I want to limit that `Set` of fields to those that are for subclasses of `DbModel`, but are super _or_ subclasses of `T`, which itself extends `DbModel`. I don't need to do anything with them -- they just need to match the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

> Honestly, I'm not even sure what that type of projection is called. Any pointers?

Sounds to me that **what you need is to use [Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html)**, by creating an `Interface` where you define your `work` method. This is good, as **it adheres to the [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle**.

After that, have the classes you want to use it implement the interface (say, `class Dog : Mammal(), WorkInterface`), and don't implement it in the ones you don't want/need to use `work`.

Also, have them *override* the `work` method. That way you will be able to call the `work` method on the instances of your objects when you want it. For example, your code should look something like this:

*The `WorkInterface` interface*:

```
interface WorkInterface{
    fun work(foo:String)    //add the parameters you need
}
```

*Using the interface on a class like `Dog`*:

```
//implementing and extending are done the same way in Kotlin, after the colon
class Dog : Mammal(), WorkInterface{
    //define your attributes, methods etc..

    //override all the methods defined in the interface
    override fun work(foo: String){
        //implement the specific code you want this to do
    }
}
```

After which you can use on your `Dog` instance like `myDog.work("whatever")`.